# HTTP endpoint for AWS Managed Kafka?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-msk

Can a HTTP endpoint be setup with AWS's Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK)? With which we can send data using HTTP POST? We can't use the AWS SDK because the client is very thin (it is our CDN actually) and it can only do simple HTTP requests like cURL/wget.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the KAFKA REST Proxy within the same VPC where you are running MKS , quoting from [MSK FAQ's](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/faqs/) . Refer to the Kafka REST Proxy [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/index.html) for the APIs

> REST Proxy: A REST proxy can be installed on an instance running within your VPC. REST proxies allow your producers and consumers to communicate to the cluster through HTTP API requests.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks Soumen! I'm a bit confused by how licensing works around Confluent. Will we need an enterprise license or not, if we use this REST proxy plugin?

Comment: OK so i see that the it is has a Confluent Community License , which allows you to do many things except for creating a SaaS , PaaS or IaaS platform or something which competes with the Confluent platform more details here https://www.confluent.io/blog/developers-guide-confluent-community-license . If you are not in any of the ones which i mentioned then you should be good.